# Point TagSoup Parser to use HTML5 version

Tags: html, tag-soup

I want TagSoup settings to use HTML5 standars. 
I am using tagsoup Parser which is adhearing to HTML4 which doesn't allow a `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag. hence, parsing a wrong HTML. However, HTML5 allows the use of the same. How do I makethe tagsoup (org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup) to use HTML5 standards.
eg,

```
<a>
  <div></div>
</a>
```

becomes,

```
<a></a>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the following structure:

```
<a>
  <li></li>
  <p></p>
</a>
```

became,

```
<a>
  <li></li>
</a>
<p></p>
```

I resolved it by using a custom HTMLSchema:

```
private class CustomHTMLSchema extends HTMLSchema
{
    public CustomHTMLSchema()
    {
        super();
        ElementType elA = getElementType("a");
        elA.setModel(elA.model() | M_BLOCK);
    }
}
```

...

```
saxParser = SAXParserImpl.newInstance(null);
saxParser.setProperty(Parser.schemaProperty, new CustomHTMLSchema());
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked in my case too. But I had to go for a different approach as I couldn't do this for every use case. Thanks anyway,